# Find which element in an array contains a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

If I have an array like this

```
["one","two","three","hello","world","bar"]
```

How would I find which object in the array is "Hello"?

Comment: It is very simple. Google is full of answers to such easy questions. Try using `find` or `findIndex` function in JS as per your requirement

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr = ["one","two","three","hello","world","bar"];

const index = arr.indexOf("hello");
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) or [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Both return the index of the item if it is in the array or `-1` if it is not.

```js
const array = ["one","two","three","hello","world","bar"]
const result = array.findIndex(item => item === "hello");
if(result === -1) console.log("Not found");
else console.log(`"hello" found at index ${result} in array: array[${result}] = ${array[result]}`);
```

```js
const array = ["one", "two", "three", "hello", "world", "bar"]
const result = array.indexOf("hello");
if (result === -1) console.log("Not found");
else console.log(`"hello" found at index ${result} in array: array[${result}] = ${array[result]}`);
```